# escaping xml chars in jsp exception

Tags: java, jsp, escaping

When trying to run the following bit of code:

```
<c:out value="${<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(variable.content)%>}"
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
 The function escapeXml must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified.
```

Do you have any idea in how to fix it or workaround it?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve by putting a scriptlet inside a an EL expression `${}`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis would just like the content of variable.content escaped. Otherwise < > and " are going to be seen as special chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you are getting is weird, you'll have to post the full stack trace, but you are not allowed to use scriptlets as you are attempting to in an Expression Language expression. In other words, this

```
${<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(variable.content)%>}
```

is syntactically incorrect. Get rid of the `${}`.

Comment: If I do that I cannot use variable.content which is declared as JSTL tag variable

Comment: Yes the scriplet I added it only because did not work without (same exception) and I thought might have been that the issue. Howver yes I will remove it.

Comment: @Roller You can't mix EL with scriptlets in this fashion. Alternatively, you can use scriptlets to get the request attribute `variable`, get its `content` field, escape it and use that value directly in the `<c:out../>`.

Comment: I tried out without scriptlet c:out value=<StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(variable.content)> same exception. Is not possible to use StringEscapeUtils in EL?

Comment: @Rollerball No, but there are alternatives. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_escapexml.htm).